# Are single quotes needed in shell date format specifiers

Tags: bash, date

I have a question about formatting the date command. I am not sure if the bullet points are necessary. 
Most of the times I use:

```
date +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

and sometimes I forget the bullet points, but it works fine

```
date +%Y-%m-%d
```

I found this gem a long time ago, and use it when the date needs a hyphen:

```
date -I
```

the "-I" flag gives me the same formatting as the two above.

I do not see the " -I " (capital eye) flag in the man pages for "date" 
if the %Y%m are format specifiers, what is the "-I" flag called?  Also, are there other format specifiers shortcuts out there.  It would be nice to get a shortcut for YYYY.mm.dd (the dots instead of hyphen)

Comment: `%Y-%m-%d` and `'%Y-%m-%d'` parse to **exactly** the same string. There's no difference whatsoever; `date` can't even tell which one of the two you used.

Comment: (and BTW, date is **not** part of bash; it's an external command that lives typically in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, and it behaves the same way whether it was started by bash, zsh, `/bin/sh`, fish, Python, Java, etc; bash **does** have its own date formatting capabilities, but the `date` command isn't part of them -- bash's built-in date formatting is actually part of `printf`).

Comment: @Charles Duffy - is date GNU ?

Comment: GNU makes a version of `date`. It's not *the only* version of `date` -- there's a BSD version, a busybox version, etc; which one you have depends on your OS vendor.

Comment: BTW, for bash's built-in date formatting (in 4.3 or newer), one might use: `printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' -1`

Comment: (got the version wrong above -- that should be 4.2, not 4.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` symbol has almost no special meaning in shell, so that it normally does not have to be quoted, e.g. `date +%Y-%m-%d` is good enough.

`%` and `%n` words can be used to refer to a [shell job](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) but they are not universally expanded by [shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

`%` does have meaning in `crontab` though, so that it needs to be quoted there with a backslash `\`, e.g. `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`.

Answer (score 1):

`date -I` is documented for GNU date, from [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html):

> `-I[FMT], --iso-8601[=FMT]`
>                 output date/time in ISO 8601 format.  FMT='date' for date only
>                 (the default),

But it doesn't work for, say, [FreeBSD date](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date(1)), which does know about `date +%Y-%m-%d` though.